# Why is margin outside the parent div bounds

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I have a margin on an `h2` element, the margin is outside the parent div, so the background of the parent div doesn't cover the margin.

If I make it a padding it fixes.

I want the second behavior with padding, where the gray background is covering the margin.

But this doesn't work with margin, I want to know why it doesn't work with margin and works with padding, and I want it to work with margin usage.

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  background: #ccc;
}

.margin {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.padding {
  padding: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
<div id="app">
  <h2 class="margin"> Title </h2>
</div>
</div>
<p>Content</p>
<div class="section">
<div id="app">
  <h2 class="padding"> Title2 </h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because margins collapse.

Answer (score 0):

Try to display your container elements as block elements to constrain the child elements.

```
section {
display:block; width:100%; background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Margin is space **between two elements** while the padding is space **within** the elements.

Your background applies to only elements and not to space between elements i.e. the margin.

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  background: #ccc;
  border:1px solid transparent;
}

.margin {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.padding {
  padding: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
<div id="app">
  <h2 class="margin"> Title </h2>
</div>
</div>
<p>Content</p>
<div class="section">
<div id="app">
  <h2 class="padding"> Title2 </h2>
</div>
</div>
```